# RuleEngine or Templating language to transform JSON dynamically

Tags: c#, rule-engine, templating-engine

I have a json that needs to be transformed dynamically into another json. I want to map a property from input json to the property of target json, while mapping i also want to apply rule. Below is sample pseudo code

```
if (input.State == "TX")
   output.TaxRate = 12.00
 else
   output.TaxRate = input.Rate..
```

These rules and target json structure keeps changing very often. So I was looking for templating language or rule engine where i can dynamically apply rules or map to different target json.

I looked into [Microsoft Rules Engine](https://github.com/microsoft/RulesEngine) that use JSON based Template. But as most of the other open source rule engine it does not execute actions/methods when condition is true. It only evaluates the linq expression and returns boolean. Has anyone try to extend this rule engine to execute action/method dynamically?

I am open for any other suggestions, guidelines. I prefer templating language so i can provide UI to edit template dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by execute action?  Why would you want to execute an action while parsing/transforming a data structure?  Generally, you should transform your object and *then* execute any desired actions.

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ ?

Comment: @dx_over_dt If i use RulesEngine then it would not do transformation. It would ONLY evaluate the condition. You need to execute method that would actually transform or map the property to target object when condition is true

Comment: It's probably been too long since I've used C#.  This would be pretty simple in Node/JS and foolproof in TypeScript.  Could you not just use a series of chained Linq queries?

Answer (score 1):

As of v3, RulesEngine provides support for actions - https://github.com/microsoft/RulesEngine/wiki/Actions

It supports OutputExpression which can do trasformation using expression.
If you need more complex transformation, you can even create your own action and plug it in RulesEngine